# How to load Play Evolutions module within a custom ApplicationLoader?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4, play-slick, playframework-evolutions

I'm using Play-Slick and Play-Slick-Evolutions modules with Play 2.4, and I wrote a very simple custom `ApplicationLoader` like this:

```
class Cards9AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = new Cards9Components(context).application
}

class Cards9Components(context: Context) extends
     BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
  lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)
  override lazy val router = Router.from {
    case GET(p"/")              => Action { request => Ok }
    case GET(p"/assets/$file*") => assets.versioned("/public", file)
  }
}
```

The problem is that Evolutions scripts are not being applied. I think it isn't a configuration problem, because the Evolutions apply screen appears when I use the default `ApplicationLoader` provided by Play.

Is there a way to initialize the Evolutions module within a custom `ApplicationLoader`?